# Binary search tree segmentation fault

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers, binary-search-tree

This program is meant to take strings from an input file, sort them alphabetically to make a signature, then insert the signature as a key for a BST node. The word the signature was created from is then stored in a vector of strings linked to the key. Any words afterwards who's signature is the same is then pushed back onto the same vector, etc. I am getting a segmentation fault, will show exact location below.

BST.h

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Node;

class BST {
  private:
   class Node {
     public:
      string key;
      Node *left, *right;
      vector<string> data;
     Node(string k, Node *l, Node *r, vector<string> d) : key{k}, left{l}, right{r}, data{d} {};
   };
   Node *root;
   void traverse(void (*f)(const string& key, vector<string>& value), Node* root);
  public:
   BST();
   ~BST();
   Node* find(Node* root, const string& key);
   void insert(Node *&root, const string& key);
   vector<string>& operator[](const string& key);
   void traverse(void (*f)(const string& key, vector<string>& value));
};

#endif
```

BST.cc

```
#include "BST.h"

BST::BST()
{
   root = nullptr;
}

BST::~BST()
{
   delete root;
}

BST::Node* BST::find(Node* root, const string& key)
{
   if(!root) return nullptr;
   if(root->key == key) return root;
   else if(root->key > key) return BST::find(root->left, key);
   else return BST::find(root->right, key);
}

void BST::insert(Node *&root,const string& key)
{
   if(!root)
   {
      vector<string> data;
      root=new Node(key, nullptr, nullptr, data);
   }
   else if(root->key >= key) BST::insert(root->left, key);
   else BST::insert(root->right, key);
}

vector<string>& BST::operator[](const string& key)
{
   Node* temp=BST::find(root, key);
   if(temp!=nullptr)
   {
      return temp->data;
   }
   else
   {
      BST::insert(root, key);
      return (BST::find(root, key))->data;
   }
}
```

The following 2 member functions are what gives the segmentation fault

```
void BST::traverse(void (*f)(const string& key, vector<string>& value))
{
   Node* tRoot=root;
   if(tRoot)
      traverse(*f, tRoot);
}


void BST::traverse(void (*f)(const string& key, vector<string>& value), Node* root)
{
   string& key=root->key;
   vector<string> value(root->data);
   if(root)
   {
      traverse(*f, root->left);
      f(key, value);
      traverse(*f, root->right);
   }
}
```

Main program

```
#include "BST.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Computes the signature of the string, which is the original string                                                                                                                                                                                                         
// arranged in alphabetical order.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
//                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
// Assumes that the string w consists of only upper case letters.                                                                                                                                                                                                             
string signature(const string& w);

// prints all the anagrams in the BST                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
void printAnagrams(const string& key, vector<string>& value);

int main(void)
{
  string w, s;
  BST signatureList;
  vector<string> temp;
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open("words.txt");

  //read all words                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  while(getline(myfile, w)) {
     // compute signature and store it into the list                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     s = signature(w);
     temp = signatureList[s];
     temp.push_back(w);
  }

  myfile.close();

  // print the results
  //this call specifically gives the seg fault                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   signatureList.traverse(*printAnagrams);

  return 0;
}

// Computes the signature of the string, which is the original string                                                                                                                                                                                                         
// arranged in alphabetical order.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
//                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
// Assumes that the string w consists of only upper case letters.                                                                                                                                                                                                             
string signature(const string& w)
{
  string s = w;
  sort(s.begin(), s.end());
  return s;
}

// prints all the anagrams in the BST                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
void printAnagrams(const string& key, vector<string>& value)
{
   cout << key << endl;
   for(string s : value)
       cout << s << ' ';
   cout << endl;
}
```

Thank you for any help, cant get valgrind working on this. From what I can tell there are no questions explicitly related to my issue, I apologise if thats not the case.

Comment: What line/function/value is it seg faulting?

Comment: Attach GDB or whatever your debugger is on your platform and find out what line is seg faulting. Knowing it is in your traverse function is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking for `NULL` too late in `traverse`.
Move the variable initializations inside the conditional, or eliminate them completely:

```
void BST::traverse(void (*f)(const string&, vector<string>&), Node* root)
{
   if(root)
   {
      traverse(f, root->left);
      f(root->key, root->data);
      traverse(f, root->right);
   }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if a NULL was getting thrown around somewhere. That solved it, I can at least print the signatures now. Thank you!